# How to configure iccube maximum count of schema-backups?

Tags: iccube

Is this possible in the section `backupConfiguration` inside `icCube.xml`?

As an alternative, is it possible to create some sort of Schedulertask to delete old backups? Or is there a possibility to trigger this via the XMLA-interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure icCube to keep the last backup (see backupHistory in inCube.xml). Otherwise, you can configure a cron task to cleanup the backup directory according to your own requirements.